# VBA Find Sort and Past values

Tags: vba, excel

My data is in column A and column B (about 1000 rows). Each row in column B has a number: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. (it is possible after update not all 4 numbers are in the list anymore, but only let's say the numbers 2 and 4)

In the row2 the values are E2 = 1, F2 = 2, G2 = 3 and H2 = 4 
and they are always the same.

Now I want to paste with VBA the values in column B with offset(-1,0) under the values equal to the number in column B (the red numbers)

[image: Imageresult]

Answer (score 2):

Add some headers in A2 and B2, then code like this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In Range("E2:H2")
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value
             If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                 .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy cell.Offset(1)
        Next
   End With
   ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode =False

End Sub
```